# ASP.NET MVC two Parameter Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, parameter-passing

Well I want to pass two parameters using Json to the controller, where i use a query to get result....

Now I manage to pass one parameter(first one) but the second just wont work, if i did Price/4 is will work but adding /2 says 404 in console...

```
//Passing ID 4 and ID 3 to HomeController/Price
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#type, #States").change(function () {
      $.getJSON('/Home/Price/4/2', function (data) {
          var items = '<option>Select a State</option>';
          $.each(data, function (i, state) {
             items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text +"</option>";
          });
          $("#Price").html(items);
      });
  });
});
```

//Home Controller Function

```
public JsonResult States(int id, int ids)
    {
        using (TalyllynContext db = new TalyllynContext())
        {
            var query = from F in db.Fares
                        join p in db.TicketPreferences on
                        F.TicketPreferenceID equals p.ID
                        where F.TicketTypeID == id &&
                        F.TicketPreferenceID == ids
                        select p;

            return Json(new SelectList(query.ToList(), "ID", "Name"),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Any more just let me know....

Comment: Have you defined a route parameter for `/Home/Price/{id}/{ids}`? Or you can use `$.getJSON('/Home/Price', { id: 4, ids: 2 }, function ...`

Comment: AHHHH.... Yeah I have but your solution helped an work how it should, life saver thank you !

Comment: Note also you do not need the extra overhead of `.ToList()` or creating a `SelectList` just use `var query = from ...select p =>  new { Value = p.ID, Name = p.Name }); return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 1):

You should define such behavior in the route or use the query parameters. 
*I've improved JavaScript code with tips from [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke).*

Query parameters approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#type, #States").change(function () {
//It's better to use Url.Action helper to construct your urls,
//So that they always will be in sync with your routes
      $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Price", "Home", new {id=4, ids=2})', function (data) {              
          var price = $("#Price");
          price.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select a State'));
          $.each(data, function (i, state) {
             price.append($('<option></option>').val(state.value).text(state.text))                 
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Or as stated by [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#type, #States").change(function () {
      $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Price", "Home")', {id: 2, ids: 3}, function (data) {
          var price = $("#Price");
          price.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select a State'));
          $.each(data, function (i, state) {
             price.append($('<option></option>').val(state.value).text(state.text))                 
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Route approach:

```
routed.MapRoute("Name", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{ids}",
new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", ids=UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: Few other things to note: Don't hard code the url, use `'@Url.Action("Price", "Home")'`. The 'empty' option needs a value otherwise it will post back "Select a State" so use `<option value>Select a State</option>` or better `$('#Price').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select a State'));` and finally you probably want `$('#Price').empty();` before the ajax call.

Comment: Agree with your points. Though, if this code is in js file the `Url.Action` will not work.

Comment: In that case you pass it as a parameter to the function

Comment: Yep, there're workarounds for this (we usually use data-* attributes), nice point though, I will include them in the answer

Comment: Thanks guys helped me allot and made it allot smarter !